# Difference between Chrome Apps and Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

What is the difference between Chrome Apps and Extensions?

What can you do with apps that you can't do with extensions or vice versa?

Comment: Chrome extensions, packaged apps, and hosted apps have evolved since this question was first asked.  Google has very good documentation on each of these things.  Those with questions may want to start by checking out these pages: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps,  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Comment: Chrome will be removing support for Chrome Apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux. Chrome OS will continue to support Chrome Apps
https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Quoting from https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions:

> We’ve already had the concept of “web apps” in the browser for a few years, as something more rich and interactive than a website, but less cumbersome and monolithic than a desktop application. Examples include games, photo editors, and video players; all of these categories are viable as tightly focused apps running inside the browser. **Google Chrome is just formalizing the web app concept in a way that will be familiar to anyone who’s used apps on a smartphone.**
>
> **Extensions ... extend the functionality of Google Chrome and the websites being viewed in it.** For example, they can extend Google Chrome by adding a new button to the address bar, such as an ever-present currency converter. Buttons like this can also apply to the current website being viewed—for example, click the currency converter button to convert all prices on the website you’re viewing. Similarly, you can introduce new items to the context menu, change the behavior of the omnibox (the input field on the address bar), access the user’s browsing history (with consent), and much more. You can alter web pages too—for example, embed a “mail this” button next to every link in every page, or customize the layout of your favorite website.
>
> Compared to apps, **extensions cut across websites and web apps**; they are usually in effect across all websites (though some are site-specific). **Apps don’t combine with other apps in this way; they run standalone, like any regular website.**

*(emphasis added)*

From what I can tell, Chrome apps are just web applications that are registered with Chrome's Web Store (Gmail, e.g.). They're basically just glorified bookmarks. Google seems to have introduced them in order to make their browser more "operating system"-like, in preparation for tablets running Chrome OS. Since Chrome OS won't have any native applications apart from Chrome, they need some way for you to be able to "install" applications... even if those applications are just websites.

Extensions can actually affect the way that the browser behaves (ad blocking, e.g.). They can add buttons to Chrome's toolbars, intercept web requests, change the DOM, etc.

Comment: So Extensions could be used to extract and manipulate information from the websites? Apps are more fixed, 'programs'?

Comment: @frum: Yes, that's the general idea. I think Apps are in a very preliminary stage right now. I foresee them getting much more powerful in the near future. You'll probably eventually be able to double-click a Word document and have it open in the Google Docs App in a very thin instance of Chrome.

Comment: Alright, I know enough! Extensions really work the webpage... thast all i wanted to know. thx

Comment: Chrome Apps (either hosted or packaged) are not just glorified bookmarks.
They do allow unique functionality. Examples:

 1. Notifications permission
 2. Background pages / scripts (manifest v2 has better support).

Comment: Why when I add "browser_action" key to the manifest.json, It return a warning. `browser_action is only allowed for extensions, but this is a legacy packed app`, How can I migrate from legacy packed app to non-legacy packed ap

Comment: I have doubts about this answer tbh

Comment: Chrome Apps is such a brilliant idea. It basically allows you to have free hosting for your "website" AND free unlimited database storage (albeit more similar to a nosql database). Plus, you also get free marketing if you're lucky ;). Furthermore, all the heavy lifting is done by the Google Apps platform (member registration, payments, etc.).

Comment: Pretty sure these are dead now in favor of PWAs? https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/12/google-shuts-down-the-apps-section-of-the-chrome-web-store/

Answer (score 30):

[Here is an excellent resource from the Google Chrome team explaining the differences in detail](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/choosing).

It also contains a decision tree flow chart shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Please refer to the following link:
[(chrome app vs extension)](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions).
It basically says that there are two kinds of apps: hosted and packaged. Hosted apps **are** glorified bookmarks. But packaged apps provide you with a somewhat best of both worlds features- of both extensions and apps.
Extensions of course extend the core browser functionality providing little or no additional UI apart from what is already provided by chrome.

Answer (score 5):

There are three Chrome distribution channels for developers.

In order of increasing functionality they are:

1. Chrome extensions — little to no UI
2. Chrome hosted apps
3. Chrome packaged apps

[More information and fuller discussion is contained in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yjo36rY4Bc).

Answer (score -2):

quoting from http://www.chromeplugins.org/extensions/chrome-web-apps-extensions-spot-the-difference/

(as the explanation is very good)

> Major Differences Between Chrome Extension and Chrome Web Apps
>
> One of the major differences between Chrome extensions and web
>   applications is their location. Majority of the Chrome extensions can
>   be downloaded from Chrome Extensions Gallery whereas Chrome Web Apps
>   can be installed from Chrome Web Store.
>
> Another major difference between Chrome extensions and web apps is the
>   fact that while extensions are used to enhance the functionality of
>   the Chrome Browser, web apps run within the browser having a different
>   user interface. Unlike web applications, extensions have little or
>   sometimes no UI component.
>
> From a technical perspective the major difference between Chrome Apps
>   and extensions is the presence of “launch” parameter in apps which
>   indicates Chrome to show when user starts an application installed by
>   him/her.

Comment: -1 Wow! This is one of the worst StackOverflow answers I have ever read! You should consider deleting this answer.

Comment: This answer is very close to how Google explains the differences between chrome extension, chrome packaged app, and chrome hosted app.  I don't understand all the down votes.

Comment: +devdanke It's getting downvoted because it's **just** copied from another site ([SO:Plagarism](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says "Do not [just] copy ... use their words and ideas to support your own"), and it does a poor job fully answering the question (like the similar Google articles, which is why people end up here).

Comment: It mentions where it's from (so the plagiarism accusation isn't fair, since it doesn't "just" use their words, but references them, too.) - but I do agree, that the text isn't that useful / approachable...

Comment: whoever thinks its copied answer, just look at the answered time. Both are exact time "answered Mar 17 '11 at 15:28".  @TravisBemrose

Comment: @Bala, the issue isn't that Alastair copied another answer on this page, but copied an answer from another site without explaining / expanding on / adding to it.