# How to create a Chrome App or Extension maybe for my HTML app?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a simple HTML app. Its just a single HTML page with all the javascript and css styling. I want to make Chrome app or Extension out of it.

**What is difference between Chrome App and Chrome Extension?** I am confused...

So is it possible to do so?

Comment: OK so is it possible that I can create a chrome app from my HTML app? If yes then how should I proceed?...

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Comment: Yeah i did read the documentation. But i was confused about making an app or an extension for my html app. My app made required network connection as it needed to call an API. I made an extension however because for an app i think you either need to host the app on server for it to run or there are packaged apps which work offline. So an extension worked fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Chrome web app is something which runs in its own Chrome browser instance and does not have any global impact upon the browser. Basically, it's just a website running in its own Chrome frame. Some files may require local storage, but will only be used in that browser instance.

An extension runs globally on your browser - so it'll be present regardless of which page you're viewing. They modify the browser itself in order to add global functionality.

Edit: On searching, this has already been answered here - [Difference between Chrome Apps and Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341206/difference-chrome-apps-and-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Building a Chrome Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html). There you'll find really good tutorial and it might help you in creating applications and extensions for Chrome.