# How are Chrome apps and extensions differ from a developer's perspective?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The title itself is the question. I am aware of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341206/difference-between-chrome-apps-and-extensions), but it still doesn't answer my question entirely. What's the difference in the following aspects or even beyond?

- **API**: Do they share the same API or one is the superset of the other?
- **Technology**: Extensions use HTML/CSS/Javascript, but apps?
- **Capability**: Is there anything that an app can do but extension can't or vice versa?
- **Security**: w.r.t. access to file system, system resources etc.
- **Location**: Extensions are stored on local file system, but apps?

Comment: FYI, apps are deprecated except on ChromeOS, see the [official announcement](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).

Comment: Yes, I already noticed that, still willing to know what it "was" as compare to extensions

Comment: to make the question on-topic show us your research. from your questions its clear its zero so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341206/difference-between-chrome-apps-and-extensions